# How to delete values in array type object in parse.com class

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a class on parse named as "UserData", containing a column name "usersports" which is an array type, I added the values successfully in that array, now I have to remove all the values, whenever I insert a new entry

```
login_data.addAllUnique("usersports",selected_sport_list);
```

where `selected_sport_list` is my array list containing sports, and `login_data` is the parse object

```
    private class SaveUserDataToParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            private Context context;
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            public SaveUserDataToParse(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    //Do your loading here
                     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Sportapp.USERDATA);
                     query.whereEqualTo(Sportapp.USER_GOOGLE_ID, google_id_from_preference.trim());
                     ParseObject login_data = query.getFirst();

                     if (login_data != null)  {

                          login_data.put(Sportapp.USER_CITY, User_city);
                          login_data.put(Sportapp.USER_STATE, User_state);
                          login_data.put(Sportapp.USER_COUNTRY, User_country);

                          if(!selected_sport_list.isEmpty()){
                            login_data.addAllUnique(Sportapp.USER_SPORTS,selected_sport_list);


                              //login_data.removeAll(Sportapp.USER_SPORTS,selected_sport_list);
                          }
                          login_data.saveInBackground();
                     }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "finish";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Data has been successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Since I got stuck, with the above code I am able to add data in parse array.
But executing this code I have to remove the containing data of array on parse.

Comment: please paste your code here.

Comment: i just edited my post

Answer (score 2):

remove this line in your code :-
login_data.addAllUnique(Sportapp.USER_SPORTS,selected_sport_list);

and add this :-
login_data.put(Sportapp.USER_SPORTS,selected_sport_list);

Comment: well, i got your point but i have to store array of Strings like ["Basketball","Cricket","Hockey"], because i need to sort/search this string, for this reason i need to use  login_data.addAllUnique(key,value);

Comment: you can put array of string in put method. if you want to sort/search then you should use another method to sort/search.

Comment: thank you @rajat i tried this and it all working fine.
thanks a lot